# ImageRenderer not saving any image to the photo gallery

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm triying to save a screenshot of my MessageView, I'm using the new API from iOS 16 `ImageRenderer`, for some reason it is not saving any image to the gallery, or, some times is saving a blank image. If I use a different view, like a Text view with a "hello" string, then the image is saved perfectly fine. What am I missing here? It's like the `MessageView` has no content when the snapshot is made?

```
import Speech
import SwiftUI

struct MessageView: View {
    var chatId: UUID
    @EnvironmentObject var chatViewModel: ChatView.ChatViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(chatViewModel.chats.filter { $0.id == chatId }) { chat in
                    ForEach(chat.messages) { message in
                        messageViewGenerator(message: message)
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }

    func messageViewGenerator(message: Message) -> some View {
        HStack {
            if message.role == .user { Spacer() }
            Text(message.content)
                .padding()
                .background(message.role == .user ? .blue : .gray.opacity(0.7))
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20))
            if message.role == .assistant || message.role == .system { Spacer() }
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView: View {
    var chatId: UUID
    @EnvironmentObject var chatViewModel: ChatViewModel
    @Environment(\.displayScale) var displayScale
    @FocusState private var isEditing
    @State private var isTranscriptionLongEnough = false
    private let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()

    var messageViewContainer: some View {
        MessageView(chatId: chatId)
            .environmentObject(chatViewModel)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            messageViewContainer
            HStack {
                TextField("Enter a message...", text: $chatViewModel.currentInput)
                    .onAppear {
                        isEditing = true
                    }
                    .focused($isEditing)

                Button {
                    if !chatViewModel.currentInput.isEmpty {
                        chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId)
                    }
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "paperplane")
                }
                Button {} label: {
                    Image(systemName: "mic.circle.fill")
                }
                .onLongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.1, maximumDistance: .infinity, pressing: { isPressing in
                    if isPressing {
                        startRecording()
                    } else {
                        stopRecording()
                    }
                }, perform: {})
            }
            .padding()
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        turnSpeechSynthesisOnandOff()
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: chatViewModel.isSpeechSynthesisPaused ? "speaker.slash.fill" : "speaker.3.fill")
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: messageViewContainer)
                        renderer.scale = UIScreen.main.scale
                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(renderer.uiImage!, nil, nil, nil)
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            chatViewModel.isSpeechSynthesisPaused = true
        })
    }

    func turnSpeechSynthesisOnandOff() {
        chatViewModel.speechSynthesizer.stopSpeaking(at: .immediate)
        chatViewModel.isSpeechSynthesisPaused.toggle()
    }

    func startRecording() {
        // Solicitar permiso para acceder al micrófono
        SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { authStatus in
            if authStatus == .authorized {
                // Iniciar reconocimiento de voz
                let recognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer(locale: Locale.current)
                let request = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()

                recognizer?.recognitionTask(with: request) { result, _ in
                    if let result = result {
                        let transcription = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                        if !transcription.isEmpty {
                            isTranscriptionLongEnough = true
                            chatViewModel.currentInput = transcription
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Configurar entrada de audio desde el micrófono
                let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
                do {
                    try audioSession.setCategory(.record, mode: .default)
                    try audioSession.setActive(true)

                    let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode
                    let recordingFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)
                    inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recordingFormat) { buffer, _ in
                        request.append(buffer)
                    }

                    audioEngine.prepare()
                    try audioEngine.start()
                } catch {
                    // Manejar errores de configuración del audio
                    print("Error al configurar la grabación de audio: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func stopRecording() {
        audioEngine.stop()
        audioEngine.inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
        if isTranscriptionLongEnough {
            chatViewModel.sendMessage(chatId: chatId)
            isTranscriptionLongEnough = false
        }
    }
}

struct ChatView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChatView(chatId: UUID())
            .environmentObject(ChatView.ChatViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like a lot of code is dependent on the ChatViewModel - which is not included. Would you be able to add this so we can run the code? Or if not possible, could you ensure the code you provide runs without the view model?

Comment: I saw the problem, ImageRenderer does not support ScrollingView, as soon as i removed the Scrollview, the screenshot worked, this is a shame, what im supposed to do? If you know of any library that can create an image or PDF from a view please let me know!

Comment: You could try recreating the on screen view without the scrollview and save that. You would just have to track what is on screen.

Comment: @Yrb I fixed the problem following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rDQ5ENvJxyc